# PayPal IPN discount variable

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am using PayPal IPN to process payments on my website. I would like the user to be able to enter a discount code and the value (amount or percentage) passed through to PayPal and calculated.

I have been looking around the web but can only seem to find the following:

```
Use discount_amount_cart to charge a single discount amount for the entire cart.

Use discount_amount_x to set a discount amount associated with item x

Use discount_rate_cart to charge a single discount percentage for the entire cart.

discount_rate_cart - Applies to entire cart however, this variable will only work with the "Upload" Method. Not the standard Add to Cart variables.
```

After testing these out in my request string:

`...&discount_amount_cart=10&...`

PayPal doesn't seem to recognise this discount. Does this actually exist any more in PayPal IPN?

thanks for your help!

Comment: If you are still unsure about this, Id suggest you see the document I referenced in my answer below. Its very much possible to do what you are asking. Its also very straightforward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can!!!

Here is a full list of Paypal Variables, and the associated documentation.

Ive just used discount_amount_cart myself!

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HH0D0TA

Comment: Thanks Phil, I seem to have asked a basically stupid question.

Comment: @EJP Give me an up vote or two on my comments &/or answer and I might forgive you. ;-)

Comment: Note in my previous comment the words "I believe" -- I suspect the crux of the varying results, here, is due the confusion created by the multitude of PayPal "solutions".  It's hard to tell if we are all talking about the same PayPal feature.  Am I the only one confused, here?

Comment: My comments, solution and the documentation I linked to above all pertain specifically to the PayPal IPN as per the question asked.

Comment: @ReverseEMF You really should post a new question to deal with your issue. However, as a pointer, I'd suggest making sure you aren't passing too much info over to PayPal/IPN with your transaction. PayPal clip the querystring after a certain number of characters, and this can result in important info being lost from the IPN return/communication process. In such circumstances this can have very unexpected consequences.

Comment: @PhillHealey is it possible to have a general discount applied to the total value and also some discount associated with an item?

Comment: @Patricia no, for that you would need to manually discount the item price. discount_amount_cart is specifically for a cart level discount for use with coupons etc.

Answer (score -2):

No ! PayPal doesnt offer any discounts, you need to manually calculate discount in your application & send it to paypal. I have developed a Ruby on Rails application that calculates Billing information using Stripe & PayPal. By the way which language are you programming in ? So that i can help you more on how to go for it.

Comment: I was hoping PayPal allowed me to add a line item `Discount` with a negative value but it doesn't. I created a PHP function then sent the discounted amount to Paypal. Thanks

Comment: Not true. See my answer for a link to the documentation and a list of the usable variables. You can very much send discounts over to Paypal using the querystring.

Comment: @dclawson - You need to send it a positive amount since this is a discount. Sending a negative discount would actually be a price increase since its a double negative.

Comment: This answer is just so wrong! Take a look at my CORRECT answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924799/paypal-ipn-discount-variable/17028793#17028793